# How to search a custom field in Sharepoint Foundation 2010

Tags: search, sharepoint-foundation, custom-list

I'm trying to make the search server to look inside fields that are not in custom definition. For example i've a document library and i had the column MyCol... If i search and put in the query string MyCol:Value this cannot find the results even if Value is exactly the content of the column..

I tried also to create a Custom Column at Site Collection level and then add the colum from this "template"...

What i'm doing wrong? Does Search Server admit custom fields in Foundation like in Enterprise version of sharepoint?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you crawl a custom field tyou get a crawled property. To be able to search for values in the custom field you have to map the crawled property to a new or existing managed property.

Comment: Where can i find this propery to set? I looked for it inside central admin and also in the site collection settings without success.. Thank you!

Comment: By GUI it's in Central Admin -> Manage Service Applications -> {Name of Search Service} -> Under Queries and Results select Metadata Properties. Read more: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff621097.aspx

Comment: Mmm inside my Central Admin -> Manage Service Applications there's no Search Service.. I'm using foundation... Could the problem be located there?

Comment: If you don't have a search service, you shouldn't be able to search at all, unless I'm missing something...

Comment: I have only these services:
Application Discovery and Load Balancer Service Application  
Application Discovery and Load Balancer Service Application Proxy_d1c587d4-34b1-497f-b279-8fa88d172a00  Business Data Connectivity Service  Business Data Connectivity Service Application 
Business Data Connectivity Service Application Proxy 
Security Token Service Application  
Usage and Health data collection

And the search on the doc lib or site collection works.. To me in foundation there's the limitation you cannot configure the search server!

Comment: In the Foundation edition you can only execute searches on the site with CAML. The Search Service is only available with Standard edition. See also Editions Comparisons: http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/en-us/buy/pages/editions-comparison.aspx