# "Search this Site" function not working in my sharepoint site

Tags: search, search-results

When I try search a record my on my site using "Search this Site" search bar it seems to not work. Do I have to set it up first or what does the search bar even search?

Thank you.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, here's a much better way to implement the search box solution, with very little coding needed. The steps are in SharePoint 2010, because that's what I have, but hopefully they are similar in 2013.

1. In the view where you want to add the search box, go to **Site Actions** -> **Edit Page**
2. Click on **Add a Web Part**. Select Category: **Forms** and Web Parts: **HTML Form Web Part**. Click **Add**.
3. (Optional but recommended) In your new HTML Form Web Part, pull down the web part menu and select **Edit Web Part**. 
   Under Form Content Editor, click on **Source Editor...**. 
   A text editor pops up with the following code:

   ```
   <div onkeydown="javascript:if (event.keyCode == 13) _SFSUBMIT_"><input type="text" name="T1"/><input type="button" value="Go" onclick="javascript:_SFSUBMIT_"/></div>
   ```

   If you wish, change value="Go" to be more descriptive, for example:

   ```
   <div onkeydown="javascript:if (event.keyCode == 13) _SFSUBMIT_"><input type="text" name="T1"/><input type="button" value="Find Legacy AFE" onclick="javascript:_SFSUBMIT_"/></div>
   ```

and press **Save**.

4. In the HTML Form Web Part, pull down the web part menu and select Connections -> Provide Form Values To -> WIP Tracking_22415 (I believe that's your listname, and it's probably the only choice you have anyway).
5. You get a popup box for "Choose Connection". For Connection Type, choose Get Filter Values From and click Configure. For Provider Field Name, leave it as T1, for the Consumer Field Name, select Legacy AFE.
6. Click on **Stop Editing**.

The above should work so that if you enter a search term and click the button, the view will now show any record that has an exact match in the Legacy AFE column.

Comment: Hi I tried this but it seems that the page refreshes but dosnt find anything ?

Comment: As we established in our private chat, your values all have 2 spaces in them, so I suggest that you replace the Source Code with the following: `<div onkeydown="javascript:if (event.keyCode == 13) { $('#T1').val($('#T1').val().replace(/\s+/g,'  ')); _SFSUBMIT_}"><input type="text" id="T1" name="T1"/><input type="button" value="Find Legacy AFE" onclick="javascript:{ $('#T1').val($('#T1').val().replace(/\s+/g,'  ')); _SFSUBMIT_}"/></div>` Note that the second argument of the replace function has 2 spaces in it. This will change any number of spaces in the search string to 2 spaces.

Comment: so my view, I need to have a script editor part with the code above, and also a HTML FORM web part?

Comment: No, use the above as the code in the html form web part.

Comment: When I open the Source editor, and replace the code with the one above it cancels out saying, " Cannot retrieve properties at this time" and also cannot save your changes

Comment: Maybe it doesn't like the jquery. Try this instead: `<div onkeydown="javascript:if (event.keyCode == 13) { document.getElementById('T1').value = document.getElementById('T1').value.replace(/\s+/g,'  ')); _SFSUBMIT_}"><input type="text" id="T1" name="T1"/><input type="button" value="Find Legacy AFE" onclick="javascript: document.getElementById('T1').value = document.getElementById('T1').value.replace(/\s+/g,'  ')); _SFSUBMIT_"/></div>`

Comment: I replaced the entire source code with the code above, but same error.

Comment: I found this about the error you are getting: [Error: cannot retrieve properties](http://moresharepoints.blogspot.com/2014/06/error-cannot-retrieve-properties-at.html). Try this: first paste the code into Notepad, and then copy from Notepad and paste in the HTML Form Source window.

Comment: Same error, is there a way to set up the main search bar that is associated with the sharepoint site? The Search This Site search bar up top?

Comment: Now we're back to my last comment on my first answer: you need to ask your SharePoint server administrator to make the field searchable. And you will still have the problem that your field values all have 2 spaces.

Comment: so once the sharepoint server admin makes the fields searchable they search bar will work?

Answer (score 0):

Check your Library Settings -> Advanced Settings, and make sure that Search: "Allow items from this document library to appear in search results" is set to Yes.

Comment: "Yes" was already chosen for Allow items from this list to appear in search results?  but it still didn't work.

Comment: How long ago was the record added? It may not have had time to be indexed?

Comment: The answers to this question might be useful: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/27731/how-to-search-a-custom-field-in-sharepoint-foundation-2010

Comment: I haven't found a definitive source for this, but based on experimentation, it looks like text fields (single line or multi-line) don't get crawled unless they've been defined at the server level as managed metadata (which Title and Name fields are by default). However, I've found that Lookup fields do seem to get crawled and indexed, so if the field you are interested in is amenable to being turned into a Lookup field, that might be a solution. I hope someone more knowledgeable than I will confirm or refute.

Comment: it has been more then 24 hours.

Comment: so your saying that only lookup fields can be searched? AND what do you mean fields can get "crawled"? thank you

Comment: Not only lookup fields, but apparently not text fields, by default. Crawled: Just another way of saying they get indexed by the search engine.

Comment: how would I get started with this process?

Comment: Your SharePoint site administrator would have to help you with making that field defined as managed metadata. It's not something a site owner can do.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution for you, if you want your users to be able to look up records by that column specifically, would be to add a form for filtering the records shown. You could add something like this in a content editor web part (html source or preferably as a file in the Content Link):

```
 <table summary="Legacy AFE Filter"><tr>
 <td><input id="LegacyAFEFilter" type="text"></td>
 <td><input class="highlightInputBasic" onclick="javascript:searchByLegacyAFE()" type="button" value="Find Legacy AFE"/></td>
 </tr></table>
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="wherever-you-have-your-jquery-library/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script language="javascript">
 function searchByLegacyAFE() {
    var legafe = $("#LegacyAFEFilter").val();
    var currentURL=window.location.href.split('?')[0];
    var filteredURL=currentURL+"?FilterField1=Legacy%5Fx0020%5FAFE&FilterValue1="+encodeURIComponent(legafe);

    window.location.href=filteredURL;
 }
 </script>
```

I took a guess at what your field name might be -- you might need to change the FilterField1 value. And this assumes you have jQuery somewhere (if not, it's free and will make your life easier, get it). You can of course get fancier with your script -- I stripped off any existing parameters from the URL for simplicity.

Comment: Hi I added the jquery.js file to site assets, then added this script in script editor. I see the input box, but when I enter the legacy afe and click "Find legacy AFE" it dosnt do anything

Comment: <table summary="Legacy AFE Filter"><tr>
 <td><input id="LegacyAFEFilter" type="text"></td>
 <td><input class="highlightInputBasic" onclick="javascript:searchByLegacyAFE()" type="button" value="Find Legacy AFE"/></td>
 </tr></table>

Comment: ****code continued*****
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="cloudsites.vzbi.com/sites/jppdatabase/SiteAssets/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
 <script language="javascript">
 function searchByLegacyAFE() {
    var legafe = $("#LegacyAFEFilter").val();
    var currentURL=window.location.href.split('?')[0];
    var filteredURL=currentURL+"?FilterField1=Legacy%5Fx0020%5FAFE&FilterValue1="+encodeURIComponent(legafe);

    window.location.href=filteredURL;
 }
 </script>

Comment: Try adding `alert("Test");` as the first statement after the `{` to see if the script is at least being called. If you get a popup saying Test, then add more alert statements between the other statements to see where it's going wrong.

Comment: I added the alert and the box came up when I clicked enter, but now im not sure were else to add it or how to debug it.

Comment: You can add more alerts like this: `var legafe = $("#LegacyAFEFilter").val(); alert(legafe);var currentURL=window.location.href.split('?')[0]; alert(currentURL); var filteredURL=currentURL+"?FilterField1=Legacy%5Fx0020%5FAFE&FilterValue1="+encode‌​URIComponent(legafe); alert(filteredURL);`  The first alert should give you what you typed in the box, the second alert is the current URL, and the third is the URL you want to go to. If not all three pop up, there's something wrong with the statement right after the last popup.

Comment: Ok so now when I added the .txt file to siteassets and linked it to content editor "web part" when a I search for a LEGACY AFE and click submit. I get this error message .....  Unable to display this Web Part. To troubleshoot the problem, open this Web page in a Microsoft SharePoint Foundation-compatible HTML editor such as Microsoft SharePoint Designer. If the problem persists, contact your Web server administrator.


Correlation ID:34e2ed9c-5987-b077-578f-f46d81e2578f

Comment: I just found out that in 2013, you have to put the script in the Script Editor, so you can go back to the way you had it before.

Comment: I Did put it in script editor and the same error appeared when clicking search..... Unable to display this Web Part. To troubleshoot the problem, open this Web page in a Microsoft SharePoint Foundation-compatible HTML editor such as Microsoft SharePoint Designer. If the problem persists, contact your Web server administrator.


Correlation ID:25e3ed9c-0958-b077-578f-f4a3447ef6c4

Comment: Can you get back to where you were when you added the first alert and it popped up? That shows that the script is being called. Then add in the other alerts as described.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21503/discussion-between-francoise-becker-and-matt-ludwig).